Port Forwarding only works with Wi-Fi
A remote job position asked me to "liberate" a list of TCP and UDP ports with no more details than the image below, in order to start my training using a remote computer through Secure Remote Worker and making calls through Avaya.

To begin with, I don't even know what means to liberate ports and since I know little to nothing about ports or networking in general, every step I took was with the help of YouTube videos and Google:

Added rules for every port in my Windows Defender Firewall.
I don't know if this is relevant but I contacted my internet provider to see if they would be of any help, and they only tried to change my private IP to a public IP and I say tried because they couldn't verify this change in their system.
In control panel, network and internet, changed the properties of only the ethernet network and converted my dynamic IP to a static IP (192.168.1.97). Although I don't know if this is necessary or if it even worked.



Inside my router configuration, in Port Forwarding (Redirección de puertos) I added the ports, names, and ranges from the list I was provided and the local IP set previously in step 2.


After all these steps, I tested the programs with my ethernet connected but Avaya couldn't work properly. I then decided to try with only Wi-Fi, and luckily for me it worked without a problem. I had limited time and couldn't make any more tests, so I don't know if will work the next time.
I don't want to waste my employer's time or mine, so I would like to know what exactly happened and if it will change in the future. I will happily provide more details if necessary.

They want you to forward the port to the server. If you don’t know how to do that. It’s a well documented process. You will want to upgrade your service so you are not behind a CGNAT.

Thank you for your answer. My WAN IP starts with 100 but whatsmyip.com shows a public IP, doesn't this mean that I'm not behind CGNAT? regarding the port forwaring, I was able to use the programs that required this proper procedure, I want to know why it didn't work with ethernet cable

You did change your IP address of your adapter instead of allowing your router to give you one through DHCP like you did with your WiFi adapter

Yeah thats the key diference, thank your mentioning it. I will undo the adapter changes and try when I get the chance. I did this because I tought it was required for the port forwarding to have the same Local IP Address as my adapter IP. If that's not the case what should be the proper Local IP Address? and how did it work?

Looking at the table, what the employer most likely meant is that they want those ports to work for outgoing connections – not to you, but from you. Unless you had some specific restrictions set up before, all of this should work by default (though calling the ISP and getting a public IP address might certainly help for some of them).
The other interpretation – the employer wanting you to set up port-forwarding for incoming connections – doesn't really make sense in the context of the massive list of port numbers. "Port forwarding" is specifically about setting things up so that other systems would be able to connect to you, and I find it extremely unlikely that e.g. Avaya would host an HTTP webserver right on your PC for something else to connect to it; certainly not all of those port numbers.
(Some of the services listed, e.g. STUN, just fundamentally aren't used like that. It would make zero sense for your computer to be required to receive STUN connections, considering that the the whole purpose of STUN is to help VoIP work when a computer is not able to receive connections in general. The same also applies to XMPP to slightly lesser extent, for example; you're not hosting your own XMPP chat server, you are connecting to the company's, so any kind of inbound "port forwarding" on your side is going to be useless.)
So tl;dr: Your original configuration, before doing anything, was most likely enough. I would actually disable those rules that have been added – keep them in the list just in case, but most likely you will not need any of them.
The two exceptions might be the RTP and maybe SIP ports, but even then I have my doubts.

I don't know if this is relevant but I contacted my internet provider to see if they would be of any help, and they only tried to change my private IP to a public IP and I say tried because they couldn't verify this change in their system.

It might help, as having a public IP address is a prerequisite for actually receiving connections to that address.

In control panel, network and internet, changed the properties of only the ethernet network and converted my dynamic IP to a static IP (192.168.1.97). Although I don't know if this is necessary or if it even worked.

It depends on how cooperative your home router is, i.e. whether it remembers and re-offers dynamically issued addresses. Many routers keep issuing the same IP address to the same device essentially forever – but on the other hand, some routers are lacking in short-term memory and offer a different address every time the computer restarts. The more likely it'll change on its own, the more necessary it is to use a static one.

That's what I initally tought and contacted my internet provider to get a public IP many times, because altough they told me that they did the change, it isn't reflected in my WAN information or in my provider system, they even scalated my case but there was no solution. Something worth mentioning is that in websites like whatsmyip.com my IP starts with 192. which indicate that I have a public.
The only instance I managed it to make work was with those rules and Wi-Fi connection and want to make sure the next chance I get to test avaya it will work again.

That's a bad way to check – websites always see a public address almost by definition, but they can't tell whether that address is dedicated to you or whether you're "borrowing" it. The only real way to know is to check what your own router shows as its own address.

In the WAN information from my router, the internet address IP starts with 100, so would that mean that my IP private and borrowing a public IP?

It sounds like that, yeah. Although the first number doesn't tell the whole story; only 100.64.y.z – 100.127.y.z are private while the rest of 100.x.y.z are public. (And similarly, 192.168 is private while the rest of 192.x is public...) But from what your ISP has said, I think it's safe to guess that you have an 100.x address from the private "CGNAT" range. If the ISP said they'll assign a public one, that'll likely take at least a router reboot or two to take effect (assuming they actually did the configuration).

Yeah my ip start with 100.127 and my ISP tried several times change it with no results (they also told me that the router will reset itself when the change its done). Should I restart my router? If so, what type of restart?

They're asking you to forward ports.    And it sounds like you are on the right track but just need some contextual knowledge.
I see you portforwarded the 2 types of ports (tcp and udp) that you were asked to forward in your router, and you said it is working wirelessly.  great job.
If you would also like to get it working over ethernet you have 2 things to look at:
Did you apply the port forwarding rules in the router to Just 1 ip or type of connection?    your wired and wireless connection from the same machine will have a different IP. check that and adjust as neccesary. you may need to make those rules global or copy them for the wired IP address of your workstation
If not, maybe undo any rules you made on your workstation involving the firewall.
but for knowledge. consider your workstation a server.
all servers on a network have a network address (ip address) and ports that they listen on for certain applications. If a request for a port comes to the network address of your network (the one forwwarded from your ISP to your router) but it needs to go to your workstation, the router needs to know when a request for a port, with out a specific network address, needs to go.
external request from your company are to your external network address and need to be explicitly sent somewhere else by a knowledgable device on your network.  the router.

To be frank, I  didn't really understand what I was doing when setting up those rules. I put 192.168.1.97 in Local IP Address of port forwarding  because I tought it need to be the same as the IP I manually put in my ethernet properties and didn't considered anything else. I want to understand if I inserted the correct IP for the port forwarding and if not what would be the correct one
